# Can't figure out how to show the list dropdown options based on the country in the URL

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I am trying to show options in a select dropdown that are dependent on the URL.

If the URL is `/1/india/checkpoint` I want to show the India options in the dropdown.
If the URL is `/1/vietnam/checkpoint` I want to show the Vietnam options in the dropdown.

The component works with 1 set of options. I can't figure out how to make the options list toggle between several option lists.

```
<Field
    name="checkpoint_entry_location"
    searchable
    component={Select}
    placeholder="Choose an option"
    label="Name of checkpoint"
    options=[
         {_.includes(this.props.match.params.country,"vietnam") && localizedKeyValueFromList(VietnamCheckpoints, "checkpoint.vietnam")},
         {_.includes(this.props.match.params.country,"india") && localizedKeyValueFromList(IndiaCheckpoints, "checkpoint.india")}
    ]
/>
```

Comment: Are you using a router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an if statement inside the render method, but there might be more *performant* ways to do this.

```
render() {
  let options = [];
  if(_.includes(this.props.match.params.country,"vietnam")) {
    options = localizedKeyValueFromList(VietnamCheckpoints, "checkpoint.vietnam");
  } else if(_.includes(this.props.match.params.country,"india")) {
    options = localizedKeyValueFromList(IndiaCheckpoints, "checkpoint.india");
  }
  return (
    <Field
        name="checkpoint_entry_location"
        searchable
        component={Select}
        placeholder="Choose an option"
        label="Name of checkpoint"
        options={options}
    />
  );
```